# Moving y axis to the middle and making two legends on each side for Plotly diverging bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am following this example code to make my a diverging bar chart but cannot figure out how to:

1. Make the entity name (A,B,C, etc) to be in the middle (at 0)
2. Make two separate legends for each side instead of one

Output Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qge7p.jpg

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

d = {'Who': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
     'Pants on Fire': [9,7,6,4, 2, 1],
     'False': [7, 6, 4, 5, 2,1],
     'Mostly False': [5, 4, 6,4, 2, 6],
     'Half True' : [4,2,5,6,3, 2],
     'Mostly True': [5,3,2,3,4,3],
    ' True': [2,4,3,6, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig = go.Figure()
for col in df.columns[1:4]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=-df[col].values,
                         y=df['Who'],
                         orientation='h',
                         name=col,
                         customdata=df[col],
                         hovertemplate = "%{y}: %{customdata}"))
for col in df.columns[4:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x= df[col],
                         y =df['Who'],
                         orientation='h',
                         name= col,
                         hovertemplate="%{y}: %{x}"))    

fig.update_layout(barmode='relative', 
                  height=400, 
                  width=700, 
                  yaxis_autorange='reversed',
                  bargap=0.01,
                  legend_orientation ='v',
                  legend_x=1.0, legend_y=1.0
                 )```
````

Comment: As far as I know, the Y axis cannot be placed anywhere other than right and left (top and bottom of a horizontal graph), so the only way is to place it at zero using annotations. Also, I don't think you can split the legend either. The only way I can think of, based on my limited experience, is to combine them in a subplot.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all 6 bars ('True',..., 'Pants on Fire') for A,B,C to start from 0 and become negative?

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for your input. Neither of the tasks seem to be easily achievable by code alone. I will create two sides separately and then join the two images. That sounds like the easiest work-around right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- following your requirement,  build traces using **Plotly Express**.  Use https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items to have *two* legends in target figure
- core to solution - need a left hand side and right hand side.  Use https://plotly.com/python/subplots/
- add traces to left and right hand side as appropriate
- finally configure layout and axes to get to visual you require

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {
    "Who": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "Pants on Fire": [9, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1],
    "False": [7, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1],
    "Mostly False": [5, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6],
    "Half True": [4, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2],
    "Mostly True": [5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3],
    " True": [2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 8],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# use two sub-plots so yaxes can be in middle...
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, horizontal_spacing=0)

# create the two figures as per question ...
fig1 = px.bar(df, y="Who", x=df.columns[1:4]).update_traces(
    legendgroup="pants", legendgrouptitle_text="Pants"
)
fig2 = px.bar(
    pd.merge(
        df["Who"],
        df.loc[:, df.select_dtypes("number").columns] * -1,
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
    ),
    x=df.columns[4:],
    y="Who",
).update_traces(legendgroup="truth", legendgrouptitle_text="Truth")

# add traces from figures to sub-plots figure
for t in fig1.data:
    fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=1)
for t in fig2.data:
    fig.add_trace(t, row=1, col=2)

# final config
fig.update_layout(barmode="relative", yaxis_visible=False)
fig.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. I did some tweaking and my plot looks almost exactly how I imagined it. There are 2 additional modifications I want to make. 
1.  different discrete color scales for each side
2. moving the legend under the plot (legend for the left side on the left and for the right side on the right)

I am trying out dividing the plane into 4 subplots to put the legends in the bottom subplots but can't figure out yet how to do the color scale on single bar at a time.

Comment: color scales are easy to accomplish https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/.  You are limited to one legend per figure (not per subplot).  Hence reason I used **legendgroup**